# Logs not printing from internal jar with log4j2

Tags: java, web-services, logging, log4j2

I'm using log4j2 (v 2.19.0) for my application. It has webservice part and the common classed and methods like dao, utils and dtos are packed in a separate jar that is used by different webservice modules. Below are the high level structure:
MyCommonObjects
-- dao classes
-- dto classes
-- util classes

WebService-1
-- WS business logic classes
-- MyCommonObjects.jar
-- log4j2 config for WS-1

WebService-2
-- WS business logic classes
-- MyCommonObjects.jar
-- log4j2 config for WS-2

Now the problem is logs from MyCommonObjects.jar is not printing any of the log file for WS-1 or WS-2. Only logs are printing from WS business logic classes.
Earlier when I used to use Log4j-1 I used to get logs from MyCommonObjects.jar but after migrating to Log4j-2 it stopped.

Any idea how to print those logs? Am I missing any configuration?

Answer (score 0):

As `MyCommonObjects.jar` is using log4j1. You have upgraded to log4j2 in your application. So it requires bridge between log4j1 -> log4j2. Add `log4j-1.2-api.jar` library.

Get more details at [Migrating from Log4j 1.x to 2.x](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/migration.html#option-1-use-the-log4j-1-x-bridge-log4j-1-2-api)

Comment: Both MyCommonObjects.jar and WS application has been upgraded to log4j-2 and this bridge jar is also present. The log4j config xml is also modified for log4j2. After all these modification, I am facing this issue.

Comment: If you have upgraded to log4j2 for both application then you don't need bridge jar. Also I would recomment to use slf4j instead so it will be not dependent on logging framework. Have you configured log4j2.xml in class path or other custom place? Jar is loaded in application?

Comment: the configuration xml is placed in a custom place and it is loaded this file like:.
ServletContext context = event.getServletContext();
Configurator.initialize(null, context.getInitParameter("log4j-config-location"));